# Javascript - add string when using document.createElement

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a callout using the Apple MapKit JS using `document.createElement` which is working by adding elements from an array that contains the data. I would now like to add a string in front of some of the elements. Here's how the callout currently looks:

[image]

I would like to add the string `Phone:`  in front of the phone number so it would read `Phone: +1 (415) 983-8030` in this example but haven't been able to work out the correct syntax here.

Here's the code for the callout that I'm creating:

```
// Landmark annotation callout delegate
var calloutDelegate = {
// Return a div element and populate it with information from the
// annotation, including a link to a review site.
calloutContentForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "review-callout-content";

    var link = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    link.href = annotation.landmark.url;
    link.textContent = "website";


    var phone = element.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
    phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;

    var addLine = element.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    var contact = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    contact.href = annotation.landmark.url2;
    contact.textContent = "contact";

    // Add more content.
    element.style.width = "240px";
    element.style.height = "100px";
    return element;
}
```

I can't work out how to add a string prior to the `phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;` line - everything I've tried so far has failed.

Comment: `element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(…))`

Comment: Or simply: phone.textContent = `Phone: ${annotation.landmark.phone}`?

Comment: Or are you just looking for `phone.textContent = 'Phone: ' + annotation.landmark.phone;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to include the text "Phone:" before the phone number value:

```js
phone.textContent = `Phone: ${annotation.landmark.phone}`;
```

Comment: This works for the Phone. I'm also trying this on the website links but it makes the `Website: ` string part of the clickable link. Is there a way to  prepend the text before the link so it's not part of the clickable hyperlink?

Comment: You will need to create another wrapper element for the link, for example: `var linkWrapper = element.appendChild(document.createElement('span'))`, and append the link to this wrapper element.